# **kwargs not working in mpi4py MPIPoolExecutor

Tags: python-3.x, keyword-argument, mpi4py

The mpi4py documentation claims that you can pass **kwargs through the [MPIPoolExecutor](http://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mpi4py.futures.html#mpipoolexecutor), but I haven't been able to get it to work. I execute the following code:

```
import time
import socket
import numpy as np
from mpi4py.futures import MPIPoolExecutor
from mpi4py import MPI


def print_val(x, kwargsstr):
    time.sleep(1)
    msg = "x value: " + str(x) + \
        ", socket: " + str(socket.gethostname()) + \
        ", rank: " + str(MPI.COMM_WORLD.Get_rank()) + \
        ", time: " + str(np.round(time.time(), 1)) + \
        ", kwargs string: " + kwargsstr
    print(msg)

    return x


def main():

    kwarg = 'test'
    kwargs = {'kwargsstr':kwarg}

    with MPIPoolExecutor() as executor:
        x_v = []
        # for res in executor.map(print_val,
        #                         range(9), 9*[kwarg]):
        for res in executor.map(print_val,
                                range(9), **kwargs):
            x_v += [res]
        print(x_v)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    """
    run on command line with 1 scheduler and 2 workers:
    $ mpiexec -n 1 -usize 3 -machinefile hostfile.txt python mpi4py_kwargs.py
    """

    main()
```

via this command:

```
$ mpiexec -n 1 -usize 3 -machinefile hostfile.txt python mpi4py_kwargs.py
```

and get this error message:

```
TypeError: print_val() missing 1 required positional argument: 'kwargsstr'
```

Note that when the commented out portion in main is switched the code runs as expected.

Comment: Is `kwargs = {'kwargstr':kwarg}` a typo meant to be written `kwargs = {'kwargsstr':kwarg}`?

Comment: You are right, that's a typo. I corrected this but got the same error. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Reading the source code, I don't think kwargs are supported. But you don't deal with kwargs anyways in `print_val`. So how about `zip(range(9), [kwarg] * 9)` as second argument and no `**kwargs` for `executor.map`?

Comment: Ah, that's disappointing. Unfortunately the function in my real application has quite a few more arguments. `executor.map(print_val, range(9), 9*[kwarg])` does the job in this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `map` supports kwargs. Let's have a look at the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/mpi4py/mpi4py/src/18c52a9/src/mpi4py/futures/pool.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)

[`map`](https://bitbucket.org/mpi4py/mpi4py/src/18c52a9/src/mpi4py/futures/pool.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#pool.py-95) indeed takes `kwargs` in its signature:

```
def map(self, fn, *iterables, **kwargs):
```

This is what the documentation says about the `kwargs` arguments:

```
Keyword Args:
  unordered: If ``True``, yield results out-of-order, as completed.
```

It is not obvious whether keyword arguments, excluding `unordered`, will be passed to the callables. We continue. The implementation is done using:

```
iterable = getattr(itertools, 'izip', zip)(*iterables)
return self.starmap(fn, iterable, **kwargs)
```

Thus, `kwargs` is forwarded to [`starmap`](https://bitbucket.org/mpi4py/mpi4py/src/18c52a9/src/mpi4py/futures/pool.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#pool.py-125):

```
def starmap(self, fn, iterable, timeout=None, chunksize=1, **kwargs):
```

with the same documentation

```
Keyword Args:
  unordered: If ``True``, yield results out-of-order, as completed.
```

The implementation looks as follows:

```
unordered = kwargs.pop('unordered', False)
if chunksize < 1:
    raise ValueError("chunksize must be >= 1.")
if chunksize == 1:
    return _starmap_helper(self.submit, fn, iterable,
                           timeout, unordered)
else:
    return _starmap_chunks(self.submit, fn, iterable,
                           timeout, unordered, chunksize)
```

Apparently, `kwargs` is not used any further, once `unordered` has been retrieved. Thus, `map` does not consider `kwargs` as callable kwargs.

As pointed out in my comment, for this particular example, you can provide the argument as non-keyword-argument, but positional argument, as well:

```
for res in executor.map(print_val, range(9), [kwarg] * 9):
```

as the second argument of `map` is documented as:

```
iterables: Iterables yielding positional arguments to be passed to
           the callable.
```

For people new to python:

```
>>> kwarg = 'test'
>>> [kwarg] * 9
['test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test']
```

where `[kwarg] * 9` is a list implementing the iterables protocol.